# timedatectl: command not found

Tags: 18.04, package-management, docker, timezone

**The scenario:** I'm trying to set timezone on a docker container based on Ubuntu 18.04 docker image. 
Just pull the image and updated

```
> apt-get -y update
```

**The error:**

When run

```
> timedatectl
```

I get

```
> timedatectl: command not found
```

**The question:** How to install [timedatectl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timedatectl.1.html)?

**What I've tried so far:** I tried to install timedatectl as follows

```
> apt-get -y install timedatectl
> Unable to locate package timedatectl
```

Thank you

Comment: `timedatectl` is part of `systemd` package.

Comment: If you had installed `ntpdate`, it disabled `timedatectl` because it could **disabled** some services tha use `systemd` in case of update

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, installed `systemd` package:

```
> apt-get install systemd
```

`timedatectl` is installed

Comment: I got error after installing `systemd` and run `timedatectl` > System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.